# Scaling from YUV 10 bit to RGB

Tags: c++, winapi, video, ms-media-foundation, yuv

I finally managed to convert, with the aid of [libyuv](https://github.com/lemenkov/libyuv), a sample of type MFVideoFormat_P010 (read with Media Foundation) and I got a buffer of 10-bit values in a 32-bit structure like this:

```
struct ar30
{
    unsigned b : 10;
    unsigned g : 10;
    unsigned r : 10;
    unsigned a : 2;
};
```

Now I want to convert these RGB values to display into my HDR Direct2D context which has a DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT format and accepts WIC bitmaps created in a GUID_WICPixelFormat128bppPRGBAFloat format.

My problem is how to scale these values. Scaling to [0..1] misses the point of HDR anyway, but scaling to [0..4] creates a too much bright image.

[image: Image scaled to 0-4]
[image: Image scaled to 0-1]

which makes me think that the scaling between this 10-bit and floating point cannot be linear. Looking the images indicates that something about the luma is wrong.

Any clue on the proper conversion?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you looking for this type of information https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/379292-Converting-Between-10-bit-RGB-and-YUV-and-Back ?

Comment: I 've tried all constants given there, also libyuv has the constants, still the same luma result.

Comment: It's not clear what you have tried, I guess you've seen that too and the associated sample https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/high-dynamic-range#option-1-use-fp16-pixel-format-and-scrgb-color-space. It can also be related to how you use Direct2D/3D. You should post a reproducing code.

Comment: The Direct2D part works because I 've successfully painted a HDR image when I have the ARGB as floats and also my color picker in HDR format works with trying float values. Once I have a correct RGB, I'm OK. It's the conversion from the libyuv's 10-bit RGB that I  take the 10-bit number and divide it by a 2048 to scale it into a range of [0..2]. The result is RGB with incorrect luminance....

Comment: According to your description, whether you want to conversion from 10 bit YUV to RGB? If so, I suggest you could refer to the thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714808/10-bit-yuv420-to-rgb-conversion